# gazebo_ros_pkgs build error on saucy/indigo

Tags: gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build gazebo_ros_pkgs on saucy/indigo, and I'm getting the following build error:

```
[ 14%] [ 15%] Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/GazeboRosCamera.cfg: /home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/devel/include/gazebo_plugins/GazeboRosCameraConfig.h /home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gazebo_plugins/cfg/GazeboRosCameraConfig.py
Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/Hokuyo.cfg: /home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/devel/include/gazebo_plugins/HokuyoConfig.h /home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gazebo_plugins/cfg/HokuyoConfig.py
[ 15%] Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/GazeboRosOpenniKinect.cfg: /home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/devel/include/gazebo_plugins/GazeboRosOpenniKinectConfig.h /home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gazebo_plugins/cfg/GazeboRosOpenniKinectConfig.py
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/cfg/Hokuyo.cfg", line 41, in 
    from driver_base.msg import SensorLevels
ImportError: No module named msg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/cfg/GazeboRosCamera.cfg", line 6, in 
    from driver_base.msg import SensorLevels
ImportError: No module named msg
Traceback (most recent call last):
make[2]: *** [/home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/devel/include/gazebo_plugins/HokuyoConfig.h] Error 1  File "/home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/cfg/GazeboRosOpenniKinect.cfg", line 6, in 

    from driver_base.msg import SensorLevels
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ImportError: No module named msg
make[2]: *** [/home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/devel/include/gazebo_plugins/GazeboRosCameraConfig.h] Error 1
[ 16%] [ 20%] make[2]: *** [/home/scpeters/ws/gazebo_ros_pkgs/devel/include/gazebo_plugins/GazeboRosOpenniKinectConfig.h] Error 1
[ 23%] [ 28%] make[1]: *** [gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/gazebo_plugins_gencfg.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Any ideas? I've cross-posted to the [gazebo_ros_pkgs issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/175).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149716/gazebo_ros_pkgs-build-error-on-saucy/indigo/) by [scpeters](https://answers.ros.org/users/6661/scpeters/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like an issue a missing dependency for dynamic_reconfigure. I've submitted a [pull request to fix it](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/176) based on advice from @dirk-thomas.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.ros.org/users/6661/scpeters/) with karma: 111 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0